# sas run time difference

Tags: sas, runtime

I use pc sas 9.4. But the server is on Linux, so instead of running my program in batch on the server I have a little script I run at the top of my program which uses a remote engine to connect. I also assign a libname and run my datasteps which create permanent datasets. However when I do this, my program runs for 6 hours, but when I run the program without a libname, meaning the datasets are generated in my work directory, the same program runs in 10 minutes. No one seems to know why that is, and I was told to just run my code directly on the unix server. I don't like the look of sas on unix, and using unix editors, saving .sas files to run them. I prefer using the sas windows GUI.  Why is there such a difference in runtime?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just connect to the server via the library or are you actually submitting your code via the `rsubmit;` statement?

Comment: %let srv=XXX_server_name;
%let cntsrv=&srv 7541;
options comamid=tcp remote=cntsrv;
signon password=_prompt_;
run;

Comment: That's what I use to log in. Then I create a libname that points to a location on unix server.  Then I write my code and use the sas run icon to submit, not rsubmit. So if I don't prefix my data setname by the libname alias, the program runs in 10 mins, but if I prefix by the libname alias, say like this,   data mylibname.results it runs for 6 hours.

Answer (score 3):

As you are not using `rsubmit;` you are actually not working on the server, only your data is stored on the server. You are downloading the data from the server to your PC before performing any calculations. Depending on your network, this will take some time.

Try this:

```
rsubmit XXX_server_name;

... Your Code ...

endrsubmit;
```

That way you will be working on the server, not just using data in a library on the server.

Comment: I tried but got an error message, saying that the file I'm trying to read from does not exist, but it does, because I copied over to my work directory, before I submitted the program with the rsubmit servername at the top and closed the program with endrsubmit;

Comment: Did you copy it to the remote work directory? Could yyou please edit you original question by including the code you tried?

Comment: @Jetzler rather than editing the original question, don't you think it may be better posted as a new separate question?  Otherwise we're stuffing a second separate question into the first.

Comment: Ok I will create a new question asking why does sas give me an error message when I remote submit.